# I have bumblebee status installed, this is my first time using it, but the powerline like themes don't have arrows

Tags: i3-wm

I am using i3 window manager. This is what is happening to me. I know it's supposed to be an actual arrow. This is currently with the iceberg-powerline theme, but this happens with most others.

What the issue looks like:

[image]

Comment: What the issue looks like : https://imgur.com/a/ZCDqjr4

Comment: I am on Xubuntu 21.10. I am using i3 with i3status for the status bar. It is supposed to look like this https://bumblebee-status.readthedocs.io/en/main/_images/iceberg-powerline.png. The difference between that and mine is mine isn't a complete arrow, it's more of a sideways M. The reason I am asking on askubuntu is because I saw someone ask a similar question, i3 related.